# Check State value for functional components in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

My component has a `state`(speciality) and how can i check this state value in my test case?

component.jsx

```
      export function SearchProviders({ changeRoute }) {
             const [speciality, setspeciality] = useState("Hospital");
             // blah blah blah
      }
```

Test.jsx

```
const renderedModule = shallow(<SearchProviders />);
const speciality = renderedModule.find('#speciality');
speciality.simulate('change');
console.log(renderedModule.state('speciality'));
```

I tried like this but its giving me error saying `state() can only be called on class components`

Comment: don't test state's data but how it affects render results

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution based on @skyboyer's explanation.

Don't test the implementation details of the `onInputChange` function. Test what is the change in the component after invoking it.

The change might be text content, component structure, etc.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function SearchProviders({ changeRoute }) {
  const [speciality, setspeciality] = useState('Hospital');

  const onInputChange = () => {
    setspeciality(speciality.toUpperCase());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{speciality}</span>
      <input id="speciality" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import { SearchProviders } from './';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';

describe('60135675', () => {
  let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const props = { changeRoute: jest.fn() };
    wrapper = shallow(<SearchProviders {...props}></SearchProviders>);
  });
  it('should render', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find('span').text()).toBe('Hospital');
  });

  it('should handle input change', () => {
    wrapper.find('#speciality').simulate('change');
    expect(wrapper.find('span').text()).toBe('HOSPITAL');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60135675/index.test.tsx (6.152s)
  60135675
    ✓ should render (11ms)
    ✓ should handle input change (2ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.217s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60135675